# Is it possible to use a CNAME to view vimeo hosted videos

Tags: vimeo

We currently host our videos with a Vimeo PRO account. Our users have accounts on our site in which we embed the standard Vimeo player. We are working with customers who for security/privacy reasons block both youtube and vimeo.

Is it possible to continue hosting our videos via Vimeo, but to embed them using an alias of sorts. (e.g. media.mydomain.com points to our vimeo videos)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a CDN, which will act as sort of a reverse proxy (man in the middle some would say) , and will allow you to place your CNAME certificates in its configuration. If you directly use a CNAME for player.vimeo.com then you'll get an HTTPS error as vimeo's certificate don't include your CNAME.